# No errors shown, but stored procedure will not execute on button click

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have 2 list boxes that store Likes and Dislikes for clients. When an item is selected, there is a button below each respective list box that says "Remove a Like" in one, and "Remove a Dislike" in another. When I click the button for either one, nothing happens. My screen just refreshes. It was working fine for a while, and I have since added a search box that is tied to a stored procedure as well. That is the only major change I have made, though not sure why it would have any affect.

I did remove the search box I had added, but that did not change anything. I changed the auto postback on the buttons to false, and that did not change anything either. I have removed databinds, re added them, nothing seems to get the buttons working.

Here is the "Remove a Like" button. Since the "Remove a Dislike" button is the same, I will not paste that code.

```
Protected Sub RemoveLikeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RemoveLikeBtn.Click

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.dbInterests)
    Dim insertProcedure As String = "sp_Delete_ClientInterests"

    Dim insertCommand As New SqlCommand(insertProcedure, connection)
    insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientInterestID", LikesLB.SelectedValue)

    Try
        connection.Open()
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox("Please select an interest to remove")
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try

    LikesLB.DataBind()
    InterestsLB.DataBind()
    DislikesLB.DataBind()
```

Here is the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Delete_ClientInterests]
    (@ClientInterestID INT)
AS
    DELETE FROM ClientInterests
    WHERE ID = @ClientInterestID;
GO
```

And here is the List box it is tied to, plus the button control itself

```
<div class="col-md-3 bgLightgreen">
    <h5>Individual Likes</h5>
    <telerik:RadListBox ID="LikesLB" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="100%" Sort="Ascending" DataSourceID="dboInterestLikeList" DataTextField="Interest" DataValueField="InterestID" Skin="MetroTouch">
        <ButtonSettings TransferButtons="All"></ButtonSettings>
    </telerik:RadListBox>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dboInterestLikeList" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Interests.My.MySettings.dbInterests %>" SelectCommand="sp_Client_Interest_Likes_List" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ClientDDL" Name="ClientID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <telerik:RadButton ID="RemoveLikeBtn" runat="server" Text="Remove a Like" BackColor="#CCCCCC"></telerik:RadButton>
</div>
```

Comment: How certain are you the proc isn't running? Maybe it just isn't finding anything to delete, or the incorrect param value is being passed in.

Comment: Or you're using AttachDbFileName and actually not checking the right copy of the database... show the full connection string (minus any password of course).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: If using SSMS, you can monitor the database transactions: under Tools, click SQL Server Profiler, connect to the server, under "use the template" select "TSQL_SPs", select the "Events Selection" tab, click "Column filters", click "DatabaseName", expand the "Like" node, and type in your DB name, click OK, then click "Run". Use the Pause and Play buttons at the top to control when the profiler is listening. Start it, test your buttons, then pause it, and look through the logs to see if the SQL came through and see exactly which values were passed in.

Comment: sp_ is just what I have been taught via my superior. I've just followed the same naming procedure.

Comment: I am using SSMS, I will try and see if those steps work.

Comment: All other stored procedures I have in this application work, same connection string, same database. Its just these two buttons that will not kick off this particular stored procedure.

Comment: What changes dboInterestLikeList that the control is bound to?

Comment: Mary, InterestLikeList is a List Box control, the data in there comes from an "Add to likes" button. There is a List Box to start that contains interests, once one is selected, they can click a button to add to a "Likes" or "Dislikes" list box.  Each box has a stored procedure tied to it that keeps track of clients "likes" and "dislikes" Not sure why I named the data source starting dbo, but that is a stored procedure I am pulling in to populate that list.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest traditional debugging:

- Put a breakpoint on `RemoveLikeBtn_Click` and check, whether `LikesLB.SelectedValue` returns the expected id.
- If yes, try to run the query manually in SQLServer Management Studio and have a look if the according record is deleted.
- If not, debug the stored procedure (execute it again step-by-step by pressing F11).
- If it only does not work in your application, check the connection string and whether you access the database in the same way (integrated security or sql login and whether there are differences in the rights).
- Execute a `GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[sp_Delete_ClientInterests] TO PUBLIC` and see if it works then.
- If yes, `REVOKE EXECUTE ON [dbo].[uspLogError] TO PUBLIC` again and grant execute to only the roles needed.

Comment: ...and I would not call a procedure/command that deletes something "insertProcedure" resp. "insertCommand".

Comment: Ok, finally back to work and going to try some of these today. Though, I should have mentioned that nothing in my Protected Sub RemoveLikeBtn_Click is working. The try ... catch will not even kick off- should show a message box that says to select something if you just click the button without selecting anything. That will not kick off either.

Comment: Running  the stored procedure through SQL Server, it executes as it should.